# Beam write to avro file serialization error

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro

I followed the example of writting AVRO file in [Beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html). But it gives me an error `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema` at `p.run().waitUntilFinish()` step. However, if I read from an AVRO file and write it to another AVRO output, it works fine. My goal is to write AVRO file from any arbitrary input source. Has anyone seen similar problems? How did you solve it?

```
public class WriteAvro {

public interface CsvToAvroOptions extends PipelineOptions {

    @Description("Path of the file to read from")
    @Default.String("test.avro")
    String getInputFile();

    void setInputFile(String value);
}

static void run(CsvToAvroOptions options) throws IOException {
    final Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(Resources.getResource("person.avsc").openStream());
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    // This works fine
    // PCollection<GenericRecord> input = p.apply(AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema).from(options.getInputFile()));

    // This doesn't work
    PCollection<GenericRecord> input =
            p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
                    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, GenericRecord>() {
                        @ProcessElement
                        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                            GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
                            record.put("name", "John Doe");
                            record.put("age", 42);
                            record.put("siblingnames", Lists.newArrayList("Jimmy", "Jane"));
                            c.output(record);
                        }
                    }))
                    .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, schema));

    input.apply(AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(schema).to("prefix"));
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CsvToAvroOptions options =
            PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(CsvToAvroOptions.class);

    run(options);
}
}
```

- Beam version: 2.11.0
- Runner: direct-runner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Schema` is not serializable which is causing this error.
You can store the schema as text and parse it at the time of DoFn setup.

Here is how you can do it.

```
public interface CsvToAvroOptions extends PipelineOptions {

    @Description("Path of the file to read from")
    @Default.String("test.avro")
    String getInputFile();

    void setInputFile(String value);
}



  private static class ConstructAvroRecordsFn extends DoFn<String, GenericRecord> {

    private final String schemaJson;
    private Schema schema;

    ConstructAvroRecordsFn(Schema schema){
      schemaJson = schema.toString();
    }

    @Setup
    public void setup(){
      schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaJson);
    }
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
      record.put("name", "John Doe");
      record.put("age", 42);
      record.put("siblingnames", Lists.newArrayList("Jimmy", "Jane"));
      c.output(record);
    }
  }

static void run(CsvToAvroOptions options) throws IOException {
    final Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(Resources.getResource("person.avsc").openStream());
  Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    // This works fine
    // PCollection<GenericRecord> input = p.apply(AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema).from(options.getInputFile()));

    // This doesn't work
    PCollection<GenericRecord> input =
            p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
                    .apply(ParDo.of(new ConstructAvroRecordsFn(schema)))
                    .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(GenericRecord.class, schema));

    input.apply(AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(schema).to("prefix"));
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CsvToAvroOptions options =
            PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(CsvToAvroOptions.class);

    run(options);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! It was because of the Schema object can't be serialized. Passing a JSON string and initialize the Schema object works perfectly!